# What is the best way to alert a user that he/she has unintentionally revealed confidential information in a post?

Tags: discussion

I've recently seen a question in which the asker obviously attempted to conceal the identity of the company for which he/she works. However, the method of concealment is insufficient. I'm not sure if it's really a big deal, but I thought it'd be nice to let him/her know discretely.

Comment: Can the confidential information be edited out by any other user (such as yourself or a moderator)? E.g. is it just text or part of an image that can be cropped or blacked out?

Comment: @Null - It's in screenshots uploaded by the asker. If someone could edit the image, it could definitely be blacked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invite him or her in a chat room and tell the user what you have discovered. That is really the most discrete way to tell the user, but it requires both of you to have enough reputation.

If the image is hosted on the Stack Exchange Imgur account, there is no easy way to get rid of it (images hosted there are kept eternally).

You can minimize the damage by editing out the confidential information and then flag the post for a moderator to remove the initial revision. That way it will be very hard to relate a random image back to the post.

I don't know if the image can be removed from the Stack Exchange Imgur account, that would be a nice question to have an answer to from one of the Stack Overflow employees.

Comment: Re: your first paragraph. Recall that only moderators can create private chat rooms, and regular users cannot even be owners of these rooms. So inviting a user to a private chat room is of limited applicability. (Unless you mean a "gallery" chat room, which really isn't that private at all.)

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for that information.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to leave a short comment immediately so that the OP can review the post and delete it. Or you can flag it for a moderator's attention. It will take less time for users who don't know how Stack Exchange works including a chat room.

Editing it yourself will leave a trace in the edit history and only a moderator can delete the part that contains the information.

Remember what you think is insufficient concealment might not be the case. Once a question is posted, it becomes public and even if the OP deletes it, it could be read by a high-reputation user if (s)he has the URL. That's why the OP should always be careful and there is nothing much you can do about it other than minimizing the damage by commenting or flagging.